# Can someone please help me with my random code generator?

Tags: python, code-generation

So I'm trying to make a random code generator. With 16 code places like this [x1gG4...]. But if I run the program it gives me an error.
Can someone help me?

```
#imports
import random
import time

#random string
str_var = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

#-----------Code
print "test"
print random.choice(str_var)

#just temporary
time.sleep(999)
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Your `print` statement is Python 2 syntax. Make it a function call: `print("test")`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to draw 16 times with replacement from `str_var`:

```
"".join([random.choice(str_var) for _ in range(16)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
random.choice(str_var)
```

This will provide you with a single random character from the string you have given.
The result maybe 'F'or 'g' or so on...
So if you want the string of length 16 places you can iterate for 16 times.

```py
 result=""
 for i in range(16):
    result+=random.choice(str_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do.

```
import random
x = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
print(''.join(random.sample(x, k=16)))
```

Comment: How can i make a loop + how can i add text before the code(i copyed your system)

Comment: Do you mean like this.  text ='some_random_string'  then you can do  print(text.join(random.sample(x, k=16)))

Answer (score 0):

Take an empty string variable. Run a loop 16 times and using random module, select random character from `str_var` using `random.choice()` and add it to empty string. Your code:

```
import random
str_var = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
a=""
for i in range(16):
    x=random.choice(str_var)    #taking random character from str_var
    a+=x

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string
rand_str = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(16))
```